# My Android Studio starts with the error in my SDK packages

Tags: android, sdk

When I start my Android studio, it shows me this error

> Were not installed: "extra-google-m2repository and tools"

I have already installed my SDK but this error kept appearing and I am also on Administrator mode already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a proxy for andorid studio. Here:

```
C:\Users\"Your account".AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml﻿
```

Then change the line about proxy configurations like this:

```
<option name="USE_HTTP_PROXY" value="true" />
<option name="USE_PROXY_PAC" value="false" />
<option name="PROXY_HOST" value="your proxy server" />
<option name="PROXY_PORT" value="your proxy port" />﻿
```